# Django Rest Framework: Send full foreign key objects in GET response but accept only foreign ids in POST payload, without two serializers?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

Say I've two models:

```
class Singer((models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Song(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   singer = models.ForeignKey(Singer)
```

And two serializers like:

```
class SingerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Singer
        fields = '__all__'

class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    singer = SingerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Singer
        fields = '__all__'
```

I've defined the serializers as above because I need the full foreign key object in the GET response for songs:

```
{
    "singer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "title": "foo la la"
}
```

Is there a way to allow POST/PATCH payloads to only send in the id of the foreign object and not the entire object, without writing a different serializer? I'd like the PATCH payload to be so:

```
{
    "singer": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "foo la la"
}
```

Comment: why did you assign `model=Singer` for both serializers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by defining read_only and write_only fields.
Also by using `SlugRelatedField`allows DRF to automatically populate it from a field on the related model.

Haven't tested this code, but the idea still stands.

```
class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    singer = SingerSerializer(read_only=True)
    singer_id = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Singer.objects.all(), slug_field='singer', write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Singer
        fields = ['singer', 'signer_id']
```

Comment: I think this works. Let me test it out and then approve. Thanks

Comment: If that solved your problem it will be greatly appreciated if you could mark my answer as correct, to help other people who seek an answer. If it does not yet solve your question, I will gladly try to help.

Comment: I think it should be `model = Song` instead of `model = Singer`.